# envdte configurationmanager Project StartOptions

Tags: c#, envdte, configurationmanager, invalidoperationexception, visual-studio-automation

I'm writing a c# console application with envdte / envdte80 (no experience with both) to open a project inside a new Visual Studio Instance. Inside this new instance, I'm trying to change the Project.StartOptions through my console application.

When I try to load the ConfigurationManager, I'm receiving this exception:
"System.InvalidOperationException",
"Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object."

My Code:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using System;

namespace AutomationProject
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ...
            EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte;
            object obj = null;
            System.Type t = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.14.0", true);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            // Attempt to create an instance of envDTE. 
            obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(t, true);

            // Cast to DTE2.
            dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)obj;
            dte.MainWindow.Visible = true;
            //dte.MainWindow.Activate();
            //dte.UserControl = true;
            dte.ExecuteCommand("File.OpenProject", projectLocation + projectName);

            //dte.ExecuteCommand("Project.StartOptions", "-break -lib:ModuleName -exec:TestName");
            // Get a reference to the solution2 object.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Solution2 soln = (Solution2)dte.Solution;
            Project proj = soln.Projects.Item(1);
            try
            {
                dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations.Item(1).Activate();
                ConfigurationManager configmgr;
                Configuration config;
                if (dte.Solution.Projects.Count > 0)
                {
                    configmgr = dte.Solution.Projects.Item(1).ConfigurationManager;
                    config = proj.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;
                    config.Properties.Item("StartArguments").Value = "command line arguments";
                ...
                }
            ...
            }
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED]**

Project was an executable, this was the reason why it can't initialize a ConfigurationManager.